# PHP should be inside HTML but its actually not

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Iam not used to PHP, but after a little research i came to the following way to output a PHP Variable inside HTML (in my case its an h1 element)

```
if($current_month != $old_date) {
    $test = the_date( 'F' );
    echo '<h1>'.$test.'</h1>';
```

unfortunately, when i look in the outcoming html scource Code it looks like this :

```
TEST <"h1"> <"/h1">
```

so "TEST" should be inside my h1 element but its actually outside.

Anyone got an Explanation or an Idea what i do wrong?

thx in regard

Comment: what does `the_date` method return? From your description of the problem one might think it is returning `TEST` rather than a date as the name of the method suggests.  For convenience you do not need to escape the quotes to echo the var - `"<h1>$test</h1>"` should do or `printf('<h1>%s</h1>',$test);`

Comment: Actually it looks like `the_date()` is echoing `TEST` and returning NOTHING, except that does not explain why the `h1` and `/h1` is being wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/#parameters), `the_date` will usually echo the date immediately unless you tell it otherwise. So instead, you need to pass in all of the parameters, and pass `echo` as false.

```
 $test = the_date( 'F', '', '', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you must at first close your if by } and then do this
and i think maybe you

```
  if($current_month != $old_date) {
    $test = date( 'F' );
    echo '<h1>'.$test.'</h1>';
}
```

Comment: of course you are right, i already do this, but it wasnt included in my Copy and Paste....if i would have forgot the closure, it wuldnt compile at all...but for the Book, you are correct

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
if ($current_month != $old_date) {
    $test = the_date( 'F' );
    echo "<h1>$test</h1>";
}
```

Or

```
if($current_month != $old_date) {
    $test = the_date( 'F' ); ?>
    <h1><?php echo $test; ?></h1>
<?php }
```

Comment: Tobe honest, i dont know why people downvote you, because this is also a good Approach, Thank You!